# Proof of Induction on zip Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to prove `∀xs, ys mystery f xs ys = map f (zip xs ys)`

Can I prove
`mystery f [] ys = map f (zip [] ys)` as base case and `mystery f (x:xs) (y:ys) = map f (zip (x:xs) (y:ys)` as induction? 
I am confused about how to split a `y` from `ys` so that I can use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: It might depend on exactly what `mystery` does (which is indeed a mystery based on the information you've given) - but providing it's possible to prove that way, you only need use induction on one of the lists. So if you can prove, as a base case, that `mystery f [] ys = map f (zip [] ys)`, for all `ys`, then it suffices to prove that, given `mystery f xs ys = map f (zip xs ys)` for all `ys`, then `mystery (x:xs) ys = map f (zip (x:xs) ys)`, for all `x` and `ys`.

Comment: The only way to you can prove this without a definition for `mystery` is to compare its result with `map f (zip xs ys)` for *every* possibly input, something you cannot do in finite time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, you need to *know* the definition of `mystery` (and `zip` and `map`) to get very far.

Now, the way you "split" `y` from `ys` has to do with a subtlety in the construction of the inductive step.  What you want to do is prove the base case:

```
forall ys. mystery f [] ys = map f (zip [] ys)
```

and then an inductive step:

```
forall xs. (
    ( forall ys'. mystery f xs ys' = map f (zip xs ys') )
    **IMPLIES**
    ( forall ys. mystery f (x:xs) ys = map f (zip (x:xs) ys) )  -- (*)
    )
```

Note that the inductive step involves universal quantification over `ys` in both the antecedent (LHS) and consequent (RHS, labelled `(*)`) of the implication.  To emphasize that `ys` is not fixed, I've used `ys'` in the antecedent.

Proving the base case will probably be easy from the definition of `mystery` (e.g., if `mystery [] _ = []` is part of the definition) and the definitions/properties of `map` and `zip`.

To prove the inductive step, fix an `xs` and assume the inductive hypothesis:

```
forall ys'. mystery f xs ys' = map f (zip xs ys')
```

Then prove `(*)` by considering two cases:

Case 1: `ys = []`.  Prove:

```
mystery f (x:xs) [] = map f (zip (x:xs) [])
```

Case 2: `ys = y:yrest`.  Prove:

```
mystery f (x:xs) (y:yrest) = map f (zip (x:xs) (y:yrest))
```

noting that, by the inductive hypothesis specialized to `ys' = yrest`, we have:

```
mystery f xs yrest = map f (zip xs yrest)
```

(As a final note, this inductive argument only establishes equality for finite lists `xs`.  Some additional work would be needed to prove equality for infinite `xs`.)